# Getting value from <%# %>

Tags: kentico

[image]

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="rptTopic" runat="server" SelectOnlyPublished="true" OrderBy="NodeLevel,NodeOrder" ClassNames='<%# CLASS_NAME %>' Path='<%# Path %>'>
```

[image]

The value for `CLASS_NAME` and `Path` are predefined at the back-end. But I'm still getting an error.

Anything wrong with my code?

Below is the whole part of the code.

```
    <cms:CMSRepeater ID="CMSRepeater1" runat="server" SelectOnlyPublished="true" OrderBy="NodeLevel,NodeOrder" ClassNames='<%# CLASS_NAME %>' Path='<%# Path %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgTopic" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="100%" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BackgroundImage") %>' />
                    <h4><%# Eval("Title") %></h4>
                    <p><%# Eval("Descriptions") %></p>
                    <a class="btn" href='<%# Eval("UrlLink") %>'>
                        <%# Eval("UrlText") %>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </cms:CMSRepeater>
```

And this is the exception I got:

```
Message: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'BackgroundImage'.

Exception type: System.Web.HttpException
Stack trace: 
at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)
at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts)
at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String expression)
at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(String expression)
at CMS.Base.Web.UI.AbstractUserControl.Eval(String column)
at ASP.inteksoft_webparts_content_topiclisting_ascx.__DataBinding__control3(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\yjseow\Desktop\inteksoft svn\trunk\MOT\MOT.Website\Website\CMS\Inteksoft\WebParts\Content\TopicListing.ascx:line 9
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.AddDataItemsIntoItemsArray(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean useDataSource)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.PostGetDataAction(IEnumerable dataSource)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.Web.UI.BasicRepeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
at CMS.DocumentEngine.Web.UI.BasicRepeater.DataBind()
at CMS.DocumentEngine.Web.UI.CMSRepeater.DataBind()
at CMS.DocumentEngine.Web.UI.CMSRepeater.ReloadDataInternal(Boolean forceReload)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.Web.UI.CMSRepeater.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__2()
at CMS.Base.Web.UI.ControlsExtensions.CallHandled(Control ctrl, Action func)
```

Based on the exception I got and after I checked my column field name is correct, I suspect that I couldn't point to the correct class name.

Once I switch from `ClassNames='<%# CLASS_NAME %>' Path='<%# Path %>'>` to `ClassNames="CMS.Topic" Path="/Shared/Topic/%"`, then everything goes well.

I'm trying to make `ClassNames` and `Path` to become dynamic controllable.

Comment: Hi. Don't you need to close tag at the end?

Comment: Is this what you mean? `</cms:CMSRepeater>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CLASS_NAME and Path Path are properties at the code behind file you can try to initialize repeater with them at the code behind file on page load. Like `rptTopic.ClassNames = CLASS_NAME;` and `rptTopic.Path = Path`. Or use `<%=...%>` instead `<%#...%>`

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="CMSRepeater1" runat="server" SelectOnlyPublished="true" OrderBy="NodeLevel,NodeOrder" ClassNames='<%= CLASS_NAME %>' Path='<%= Path %>'/>
```

Comment: WHY I NEVER TRY?! 
Initialize repeater with them at the code behind file on page load works GOOD!

Answer (score 0):

Add log from event log for the next time.
Try:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="rptTopic" runat="server" SelectOnlyPublished="true" OrderBy="NodeLevel,NodeOrder" ClassNames='<%# CLASS_NAME %>' Path='<%# Path %>' />
```

Note slash char before ending parenthesis.

Edit:
Try to use

```
<%# Eval("ClassName")%>
```

Comment: Event log added.

Answer (score 0):

Since comments can't include code tags, if you need to set a Repeater's values more than you can do in the inline tag, you can do this:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="rptTopic" runat="server" SelectOnlyPublished="true" OrderBy="NodeLevel,NodeOrder" />
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        rptTopic.ClassName = CMS.Helpers.ValidationHelper.GetString(Eval("ClassName"),"");
        rptTopic.Path = CMS.Helpers.ValidationHelper.GetString(Eval("Path"),""); 
    }
</script>
```